# adding values from one object to another one in jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcallendar and setting options is quite simple, but I have a question about combining two objects into one for example here is the code :

```
var calendar = {
render: function() {
    var source_url = $('#calendar-task').data("source-url");
    
    $('#calendar-task').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: source_url,
                type: 'POST',
                error: function() { 
                    bootbox.alert("Wystąpił błąd z pobraniem źródła danych"); 
                }
            }
        ]
        
    });
},
pl_lang: {  //polish locale
            timeFormat: {
                agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}',
                '': 'H:mm'
            },
            axisFormat: 'H:mm',
            firstDay: 1,
            monthNames: ['styczeń','luty','marzec','kwiecień','maj','czerwiec','lipiec','sierpień','wrzesień','październik','listopad','grudzień'],
            monthNamesShort: ['sty.','lut.','mar.','kwi.','maj','cze.','lip.','sie.','wrz.','paź.','lis.','gru.'],
            dayNames: ['niedziela','poniedziałek','wtorek','środa','czwartek','piątek','sobota'],
            dayNamesShort: ['niedz.','pon.','wt.','śr.','czw.','pt.','sob.'],
            buttonText: {
                prev: '&nbsp;&#9668;&nbsp;',
                next: '&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;',
                prevYear: '&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;',
                nextYear: '&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;',
                today: 'dzisiaj',
                month: 'miesiąc',
                week: 'tydzień',
                day: 'dzień'
            },
            allDayText: 'cały dzień' 
}
};
```

And I want to separate language options from other ones but they need to be joined into one option object is it possible to add object pl_lang to full calendar object ?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle and test it. I think you have a syntax error in your code.